# Javascript redirect loop until succeed

Tags: javascript, html, web

Here is an excerpt of our javascript for redirection:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var THE_URL = "http://www.google.co.uk";

    function onPageLoad()
    {
        setTimeout('pageRedirect()', 5000);
    }

    function pageRedirect()
    {
        window.location = THE_URL;
    }
</script>

<body onload="onPageLoad()">
...
</body>
```

But sometimes the page at `THE_URL` isn't available because the server is down. In this case we'd like for the current page to be refreshed so it can attempt to load the page again and again until it succeeds. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try doing the redirect after a check for the server to be up using ajax. This might help - http://maxheapsize.com/2010/04/26/how-to-detect-if-your-server-is-down-when-making-jquery-ajax-calls/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because your JS code stops executing once it's been redirected. You should probably has some server check if the site is up for you in a loop using XHR requests, and redirect only after it's been detected to be available.